# Floor function error in Desmos?

Tags: graphing-functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I ran over a problem with desmos after playing around with floor functions and want to know what is my thinking error or if the problem lies with Desmos.

In the [Screenshot](https://s.amsu.ng/jPijkHkONabN) you can see the function floor(x)-floor(y)=0. I tested the function at the point (1.2,1.4) manually and it was true, but the point is not part of the graph.

What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: I think it's trying to graph a curve when it ought to be a region, and it's confused because of the equal sign. All of the squares $[n,n+1]\times [n,n+1]$ would satisfy this

Answer (score 2):

It is an error (see my comment). You can graph

$$\lfloor x\rfloor=\lfloor y\rfloor$$

on Desmos.com by looking at the complement of

$$\{ (x,y) | \lfloor x\rfloor<\lfloor y\rfloor \} \cup \{ (x,y) | \lfloor x\rfloor>\lfloor y\rfloor \}$$

The **Unshaded** region below is the graph of your equation.

[image]

Alternatively, taking the complement of

$$\left|\lfloor x\rfloor-\lfloor y\rfloor\right|>0$$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is not difficult to show that $\lfloor x\rfloor=\lfloor y\rfloor$ if and only if $(x-\lfloor y\rfloor)(y-\lfloor x\rfloor)\ge0$.

Try graphing in Desmos

$$ (x-\lfloor y\rfloor)(y- \lfloor x\rfloor)\ge0$$

[image: floor functions graph]

Desmos does not show it accurately on the boundaries, however.

It is also the case that $\lfloor y\rfloor=\lfloor x\rfloor$ if and only if $\vert \lfloor y\rfloor-\lfloor x\rfloor \vert <1$, but Desmos errs once again on the boundary.

[image: another floor function graph]